# DB First Entity Framework data annotation for model validation stops working after first exception is caught in WPF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, ef-database-first

I'm creating a WPF registration window using a Database first approach and I want to validate the user inputs using Data Annotation. The auto-generated class is as follows:

```
//users.cs
namespace SenkouCards
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class users
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public users()
        {
            this.attempts = new HashSet<attempts>();
            this.decks = new HashSet<decks>();
        }
    
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public decimal score { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<attempts> attempts { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<decks> decks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the following partial class code:

```
//Another file also called users.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SenkouCards
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(UsersMetadata))]
    public partial class users
    {
        private string _confirmPassword;
        [NotMapped]
        public string confirmPassword
        {
            get
            {
                return _confirmPassword;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == "")
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("You must confirm the password you wrote.");
                }
                else if (value != password)
                {

                    throw new ArgumentException("Passwords Must Match");
                }
                else
                {
                    _confirmPassword = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class UsersMetadata
    {

        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Username must at least be 6 characters", MinimumLength = 6)]
        public string username
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }


}
```

Finally, here is the code that gets executed when I click the registration button:

```
//register.xaml.cs
 private void Btn_Register_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string username = Tbx_Username.Text;
            string password = Pbx_Password.Password;
            string confirmPassword=Pbx_ConfirmPass.Password;

            //if(password!=confirmPassword)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("Passwords must match","Invalid Entry",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
            //    return;
            //}

            try
            {
                users user = new users { username = username, password = password, confirmPassword = confirmPassword, score = 0 };
                Globals.SenkouDbAuto.users.Add(user);
                Globals.SenkouDbAuto.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) when (ex is DbEntityValidationException|| ex is ArgumentException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Invalid input",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
                
        }
```

My problem is that whenever a registration triggers an error in the UsersMetadata class (e.g. username.length <6), it throws an error (which it should), but then any subsequent registration entry, even if it's valid, will throw an error too. If you create a valid user and then create another invalid user, it will also rollback the addition of the valid user. It seems like it's caching the invalid model and rereading it at any subsequent save attempt, though I might be wrong.
The error handling in the partial user class meanwhile works fine.

I feel like it's something small I overlooked, but I can't quite figure it out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't use global dbcontext

Comment: So that actually worked, is it because when I was using the global context the transaction was never closing? And if so, is there ever a good reason to use a global db context?

Comment: after adding invalid data to global dbcontext it stays there. any attempt to save fails because of that. there are good reasons NOT to use a global db context